# 'setAutoTickStep' : is not a member of 'QCPAxis' with QCustomPlot 2.00-beta

Tags: qt

I'm using Qt5.6.1 and QCustomPlot 2.00-beta. And I set a new widget called "widget". But when I code

```
ui->widget->xAxis->setAutoTickStep(false);
```

it says

> error: C2039: 'setAutoTickStep' : is not a member of 'QCPAxis'

how to solve it?

Comment: It would really help to give us the declaration widget and XAxis.

Comment: Well, I get a QWidget in mainwindow.ui, rename it as widget and remote it to a QCustomPlot. And I found that setAutoTickStep was removed and was   repalced as QCPAxisTicker

Comment: I have no idea what "remote it to a QCustomPlot" means.  You still haven't posted the code you are using for declarations.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
QSharedPointer<QCPAxisTickerFixed> fixedTicker(new QCPAxisTickerFixed);
  customPlot->xAxis->setTicker(fixedTicker);

  fixedTicker->setTickStep(1.0); // tick step shall be 1.0
  fixedTicker->setScaleStrategy(QCPAxisTickerFixed::ssNone); // and no scaling of the tickstep (like multiples or powers) is allowed
```

from: http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPAxisTickerFixed.html#details

Answer (score -1):

You will need to create an object of type QCustomPlot, do a `customPlot->addGraph()`, and then access its settings like `customPlot->xAxis->QCPAxisTicker(...)`.

It appears you are trying to access a member of an object of type QWidget, which knows nothing about custom plots, until overridden.  Neither the old nor the new method will work on an object of QWidget.  You should use a new method of QCPAxis instead; perhaps

`ui->customPlot->xAxis->ticker()->setTickCount(0);`

If your problem is that you are trying to create a plot in QtCreator, you can create a QWidget in it, and then right-click on it, and do a "Promote to ...".  Make sure the QCustomPlot headers are already in your project first, and then specify the one which defines QCustomPlot when promoting.  When you say, "rename it as widget and remote it to a QCustomPlot", did you mean "promote it to"?

Comment: Anyone care to fill me in on why this was downvoted?